# Twelve Days of X-mas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

Printing the lyrics of "Twelve Days of Christmas" seems to be a fairly popular programming challenge.

As I've successfully attempted it, I was wondering if the code can be simplified even further (say no loops)?

Any feedback in regards to style and/or logic would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


verses = {
        1: ["first", "and a Partridge in a Pear Tree."],
        2: ["second", "two Turtle Doves, "],
        3: ["third", "three French Hens, "],
        4: ["fourth", "four Calling Birds, "],
        5: ["fifth", "five Gold Rings, "],
        6: ["sixth", "six Geese-a-Laying, "],
        7: ["seventh", "seven Swans-a-Swimming, "],
        8: ["eighth", "eight Maids-a-Milking, "],
        9: ["ninth", "nine Ladies Dancing, "],
        10: ["tenth", "ten Lords-a-Leaping, "],
        11: ["eleventh", "eleven Pipers Piping, "],
        12: ["twelfth", "twelve Drummers Drumming, "]
        }


def get_verses(line):
    verse = f"On the {verses[line][0]} day of Christmas " + \
        "my true love gave to me: "
    for i in range(line, 0, -1):
        verse += f"{verses[i][1]}"
    return verse.replace("and ", "") if line == 1 else verse


def recite(start_verse, end_verse):
    return "\n".join([get_verses(line) for line 
            in range(start_verse, end_verse + 1)])


print(recite(1, 12))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing your verses in a format that's a little more complicated than necessary. If you have a dictionary that you're keying by a continuous range of number (and you don't need to handle removals), you likely shouldn't be using a dictionary. Just use a list here:

```
verses = [["first", "and a Partridge in a Pear Tree."],
          ["second", "two Turtle Doves, "],
          ["third", "three French Hens, "],
          ["fourth", "four Calling Birds, "],
          ["fifth", "five Gold Rings, "],
          ["sixth", "six Geese-a-Laying, "],
          ["seventh", "seven Swans-a-Swimming, "],
          ["eighth", "eight Maids-a-Milking, "],
          ["ninth", "nine Ladies Dancing, "],
          ["tenth", "ten Lords-a-Leaping, "],
          ["eleventh", "eleven Pipers Piping, "],
          ["twelfth", "twelve Drummers Drumming, "]]
```

If you think about, lists are already indexed by number. Now you don't need to manually increment the number keys if you add a new verse. The change just requires tweaking some numbers to account for 0-based indexing (which I think is more appropriate anyways):

```
def get_verses(line):
    verse = f"On the {verses[line][0]} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: "
    for i in range(line, -1, -1):  # -1 stop
        verse += f"{verses[i][1]}"
    return verse.replace("and ", "") if line == 0 else verse  # line 0 now

def recite(start_verse, end_verse):
    return "\n".join([get_verses(line)
                      for line in range(start_verse, end_verse + 1)])
```

I also changed how you're splitting up the last list comprehension. If you wanted to split it, I would keep the iteration part all on one line, and `get_verses` on another. I also don't think the line in `get_verses` needed to be split. It isn't that line.

I'd still change some more things though:

- In `get_verses`, you named the parameter `line`. It isn't a line though, it's a line *number*. I'd change it to, at the very least, `line_n`.
- You don't need a strict list comprehension in `recite`. You can get rid of a pair of brackets by making it a generator expression that uses `join`'s brackets.
- The imperative loop in `get_verse` could be changed to a `join`ed generator expression.

I ended up with this:

```
verses = [["first", "and a Partridge in a Pear Tree."],
          ["second", "two Turtle Doves, "],
          ["third", "three French Hens, "],
          ["fourth", "four Calling Birds, "],
          ["fifth", "five Gold Rings, "],
          ["sixth", "six Geese-a-Laying, "],
          ["seventh", "seven Swans-a-Swimming, "],
          ["eighth", "eight Maids-a-Milking, "],
          ["ninth", "nine Ladies Dancing, "],
          ["tenth", "ten Lords-a-Leaping, "],
          ["eleventh", "eleven Pipers Piping, "],
          ["twelfth", "twelve Drummers Drumming, "]]

def get_verses(line):
    opener = f"On the {verses[line][0]} day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: "
    verse = "".join(str(verses[i][1]) for i in range(line, -1, -1))
    return opener + (verse.replace("and ", "") if line == 0 else verse)

def recite(start_verse, end_verse):
    return "\n".join(get_verses(line_n)
                     for line_n in range(start_verse, end_verse + 1))

print(recite(0, 11))

On the first day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the second day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the third day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the fourth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the fifth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the sixth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the seventh day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the eighth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: eight Maids-a-Milking, seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the ninth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: nine Ladies Dancing, eight Maids-a-Milking, seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the tenth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: ten Lords-a-Leaping, nine Ladies Dancing, eight Maids-a-Milking, seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the eleventh day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: eleven Pipers Piping, ten Lords-a-Leaping, nine Ladies Dancing, eight Maids-a-Milking, seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
On the twelfth day of Christmas, my true love gave to me: twelve Drummers Drumming, eleven Pipers Piping, ten Lords-a-Leaping, nine Ladies Dancing, eight Maids-a-Milking, seven Swans-a-Swimming, six Geese-a-Laying, five Gold Rings, four Calling Birds, three French Hens, two Turtle Doves, and a Partridge in a Pear Tree.
```

---

Some further things though:

- The `verse.replace("and ", "") if line == 0 else verse` seems like a code smell. It would probably be cleaner to *not* have "and" in the saved verse, and to add it when needed, instead of removing it in the special case.
- Instead of using `range(line, -1, -1)` to get reversed indices, you could probably use `reversed` and `islice` from `itertools` to get a sliced reversed iterator of the verses. That way you wouldn't need to index the list.

I'd elaborate, but I need to get going. Good luck.

Comment: Shouldn't I now subtract one from `start verse` instead of adding to `end_verse`? Otherwise, I'm getting `index out of range` error.

Comment: @baduker I'm calling it as `recite(0, 11)`. That's what I meant by switching to 0-based indexing. I'll clarify when I get to my computer. I think the code itself should start at 0. If you had client-facing code that uses `recite`, and you wanted to use 1-based indexing there, you could make indexing adjustments then.